# Apache NetBeans 9.0 ant build failed

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, netbeans-9

I was trying to upgrade my NetBeans to 9.0 following this link https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html#releases These are the steps I followed

1. Updated my brew using brew update
2. Install ant using brew install ant
3. move to directory incubator-netbeans and run command ant

Step three (3) start to build NetBeans modules, suddenly I got an error message that build failed. I have tried to resolve this problem and also tried checking SO if someone is having similar issue but to no avail. Thanks

NB: I'm using Java 8

**Error gotten**

> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/username/NetBeansProjects/incubator-netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:128:
>   Download of
>   85A67D883A879E7BF767758A8413B690DEF29735-saxon9B-9.1.0.2.jar produced
>   content with hash D366BF19293519AF7A258E23A51CC87359F06EEA when
>   85A67D883A879E7BF767758A8413B690DEF29735 was expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue using the following steps:

1. Whenever I'm faced with build failed, I re-run the ant.
2. I closed all NetBeans instances present and re-run again